# can a python class access attribute of its own object?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to create a spider without specifying a certain url. I want to create spider object, extract url from the object, and that use it as my `allowed_domains` and `start_urls` in other words, I want to do something like (note the `MySpiderObj`...I just put that expression there because I want to extract information out of the object of the class `MySpider`:

```
from scrapy.settings import default_settings 
from selenium import webdriver
from urlparse import urlparse
import csv    
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log

default_settings.DEPTH_LIMIT = 3

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    def __init__(self,url):
        self.x=url
    name = "my_spider"
    allowed_domains = [MySpiderObj.x]
    start_urls = [MySpiderObj.x]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
```

how can I do it properly? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should move all of your interdependant initializations to the constructor, and change `MySpiderObj` to `self`

Answer (score 0):

You want a factory for classes? Then you should use [`type`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) function to generate a class with needed attributes.

But in your case, as others mentioned, you should be able to make `allowed_domains` and `start_urls` attributes instance attributes:

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "my_spider"

```
def __init__(self, params):
    self.allowed_domains = [extract_domains(params)]
    self.start_urls = [extract_start_urls(params)]
```

Also be aware of [`start_requests`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.BaseSpider.start_requests) method - it might suit your needs better